# Displaying In Between Pipe - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a list of groups a set group of users is in.  I've tried:

```
Get-AdGroupMember Users | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Format-Table -Property name
```

But this only gives me output as to all the groups without the original users from the set group listed. Fairly new to Powershell so perhaps I'm missing something.  I'd like to see output like:

```
user123
-------
Domain Users
Sec Group
Bob Group

user555
------
Domain Users
```

Comment: Don't understand your question. It says "a set group of users" which implies multiple users, but later it says "the original user" which implies a single user. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking for. As you can see PowerShell is doing what you asked it to do... create a table of all `name`s from `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. The pipeline is collecting the information in order to display it as one unit.

From the looks of your expected output you actually want that data to be split up by user. Couple of ways to get that done. Straightforward one would be to build a loop and create a separate output for each.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object{
    $_.Name
    "--------"
    $_ | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    ""
}
```

That would create output like you have seen in your question. I am not too fond of that output as it is sent to the output stream and does not take advantage of objects. So, while not like your desired output, I would consider something different like:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object{
    $user =  $_
    $_ | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | ForEach-Object{"{0} - {1}" -f $user.Name, $_.Name}
}
```

Or perhaps

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | Select Name,@{Name="PrincipalGroupMembership";Expression={
    ($_ | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ";"
}}
```

This would work to your advantage as you can now export this to CSV if you wanted to with `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was going to pipe and export to csv, so that's great!

Answer (score 1):

8:21 AM

You aren't using the pipe correctly.  In object oriented programming, you first get an object then you filter it down with it's properties. For instance:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount  | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq "Doe, John"}
```

First I use the cmdlet "Get-WmiObject" to call the object "Win32_UserAccount". This includes all the user accounts on AD. Then I pipe those results into another Cmdlet "Where-Object", which filters results. Where-Object has its own properties and has to be used in its own way. "{}" are used to indicate the beginning and end of the statement. "$_." Is how you let it know it is a property of Win32_UserAccount. "-eq" stands for equal to and then I give it the string I am looking for "Doe, John".

If you are connected to the domain you can use a WMI to retrieve account data. Use this command to get all the different Accounts:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Account
```

For more specific results, you can use a different WMI like:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount
Get-WmiObject Win32_Group
Get-WmiObject Win32_SystemAccount
```

Hopefully this helps but it sounds like you need more knowledge about PowerShell.

Comment: Not sure I follow what this means "In object oriented programming, you first get an object then you filter it down with it's properties....". Sounds like you meant to say, "in PowerShell scripting, when using the pipeline..."

Comment: Look up Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership. The Identity parameter takes pipeline input (by value). The Identity parameter takes objects of 4 types: ADUser, ADGroup, ADComputer and ADService account. Looking up Get-AdGroupMember you see it emits objects of type ADPrincipal. Googling ADPrincipal doesn't yield any quick useful hits, but given it's name, it sounds compatible with Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership. In other words I'd guess ADPrinciple is a superclass of the 4 classes mentioned above. If so he is using  pipeline correctly. Pipeline isn't limited to just where-object and foreach-object.